# Spring 4 MVC: bind controller argument to HEADER or REQUEST PARAM if not found

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a way to bind a controller method argument to (1) a request *param* and, if the request param is not set, to (2) a request *header*? A kind of fallback source for the value...

I already tried the following but it doesn't work since apparently the first annotation always win.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public MyObject getMyObject( @RequestParam("paramName")
                             @RequestHeader("headerName") String value ) {
   ...
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

No only the first annotation will be applied to the method parameter. So just define 2 optional parameters like below:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public MyObject getMyObject( 
    @RequestParam(value = "paramName", required = false) String requestParamValue,
    @RequestHeader(value = "paramName", required = false) String headerValue) {
    String value = requestParamValue != null ? requestParamValue : headerValue;
}
```